# Implement an advance method in a linked list without const cast

Tags: c++, linked-list, this, const-cast

I'm making a rather simple version of a linked list which is accessed through a Link class. The goal here is to make an advance() method that will be used to traverse the list. However, the most lightweight solution I have involves using a const_cast which is undesirable. Is there solution to this that I have not considered?

```
Link* Link::advance(int n) const
{
    if(!this) return nullptr;

    Link* it = const_cast<Link*>(this);
    if(n > 0) {
        while(n--) {
            it = it->next(); //the next link in the list
        }
    }
    else if(n < 0) {
        while(n++) {
            it = it->previous(); //the previous link in the list
        }
    }
    return it;
}
```

Comment: Write two overloads; one "cost to const" and one "non-const to non-const".

Comment: You're misunderstanding my question. I want to have this advance() const method, but I would prefer not to use const_cast

Comment: Changing the const-ness of `this` and letting that "escape" the function is a very bad idea. If `*this` is a const object it leaves the door wide open to undefined behaviour.

Comment: are `next()` and `previous()` const ? what do they return ?

Comment: It is not directly the answer of your question, but for the case you don't know it, c++17 has `std::advance` in `<iterator>`. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

Comment: @molbdnilo I understand this is a bad idea which is why I made this post.

Comment: @Drax next() and previous() are both const and they return pointers to the next and previous element in the list respectively.

Comment: @AldenBernitt Yes but do they return pointer to const or naked pointers ? and is the member `next` a pointer to const or not ?

Comment: @AldenBernitt If you understand that this is a bad ides, why are you so determined to do it?

Comment: @Drax
Method declarations look like this:
Link* next() const; Link* previous() const;

Comment: @molbdnilo I am trying to write this method for this "linked list" as practice. Such a list should have a method which allows the user to traverse through the list. However, since the advance method does not change the state of the list, it should be const. Without using that const_cast the advance(0) case can not be handled. Obviously that const_cast is a bad idea, hence this post.

Comment: You may think about chaning the declarations of `next` and `previous` to `Link const* next() const` and `Link const* previous() const`. Otherwise one could remove the constness of an element `Link const* n` using `Link* n2 = n->next()->previous()`. Then you do the same for `advance` and there is no need for a const_cast.

Comment: @pschill but then you get in the situation where you cannot provide a pointer on yourself if you don't have another node next to you (e.g `next` == `null`).

Comment: @Drax I may have chosen an unfortunate formulation. This should be better: I recommend to add `const` to the return types of `next` and `previous` so that one cannot remove the constness using `next()->previous()`.

Comment: @pschill but then you can never access a non const version of your other nodes :) As in most linked list those are the only accessors. As weird as it seems it kind of make sense to be able to remove the const access if you think of `prev` and `next` in term of accessors rather than owned members, you just access a non `const` version of yourself, you are still not modifying the `const` one directly. But i agree that it is error prone and that another design might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a semantical problem than it seems.

By having the signature: `Link* Link::advance(int n) const`

What this means is that given a node instance of your linked list you want it to provide access to one of its brother node wether in front or behind it.

The interesting part is the following: **A node does not own its brothers**.

They all kind of exist at the same level. This is even more obvious given that the same node is pointed to by a `next` and a `previous` pointer at the same time from different other node instances.

The reason why your node can provide access to other nodes it doesn't own, is because he has a link to a non `const` instance of them (a `next` and a `previous` pointer). And that is the only reason. This has nothing to do with the current node instance itself and thus justify the `const` of the `advance` member function.

Now the only real problem comes from the fact that a node has no link to itself, and thus cannot provide access to itself the same way it can provide access to one of its brother.

---

There are two ways to take actions based on that:

1) Either you change the base facts of this situation, which means changing `Link* Link::advance(int n) const`, and there are multiple ways to do this like removing the `const`, adding an iterator concept and other methods, returning `const` instances etc. each takes a different approach angle.

2) Or you keep on this path which means you need to have a link on yourself too to totally respect the semantic you have given to your function:

```
class Link
{
public:
  Link()
    :
    previous_(nullptr),
    current_(this),
    next_(nullptr)
  {}

  // ...

  Link* advance(int n) const;

  // ...

  Link* previous() const { return previous_; }
  Link* next() const { return next_; }

  // ...

private:
  Link *previous_;
  Link * const current_;
  Link *next_;
};

Link* Link::advance(int n) const
{
  //if(!this) return nullptr;

  Link* it = current_;
  if(n > 0) {
    while(n--) {
      it = it->next(); //the next link in the list
    }
  }
  else if(n < 0) {
    while(n++) {
      it = it->previous(); //the previous link in the list
    }
  }
  return it;
}
```